# Ember reopen don't let me access to atributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to Ember and I'm writing my first app. I'm working with version 1.13.11.

What I'm trying to do is to override a function from a class that I comes from version `0.2.1` of a package I installed (https://github.com/RSSchermer/ember-multiselect-checkboxes/tree/0.2.1).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import MultiselectCheckboxOptionComponent from
  'ember-multiselect-checkboxes/components/multiselect-checkbox-option'`

multiselectCheckboxesPatch =
  name: 'ember-multiselect-checkboxes-patch'
  initialize: ->
    MultiselectCheckboxOptionComponent.reopen
      isSelected: Ember.computed 'value', 'selection', (_, checked) ->
        if arguments.length > 1
          selected = this.get('selection').contains(this.get('value'))

          if checked and not selected
            this.get('selection').addObject(this.get('value'))
          else if not checked and selected
            this.get('selection').removeObject(this.get('value'))

          # Added this line to fix variant of https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10286
          @set('selection', Ember.copy(this.get('selection')))

        this.get('selection')?.contains(this.get('value'))

`export default multiselectCheckboxesPatch`
```

But the issue I'm facing is that `this.get('selection')` seems to be undefined. I don't understand why since `selection` is an attribute from the class that I'm reopening. 
Also, I think this code used to work in older versions of ember since I got it from another project.

Thank you!